# Hiding External Javascript Errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling, youtube

When I link a youtube video (or any other external link) and the link has errors in the associated script file, those errors are always displaying in my console. I'd like to try disabling the displaying of Javascript errors for all external files, except the ones I select.

So for example, my console looks like this after linking a youtube video:

[image: YouTube Errors in Javascript Console]

And since I'm designing my portfolio site to display a welcome message in the console (for prospective employers) I really don't want these unrelated errors showing up, making it look like my site build is broken.

So is there any way to decide which scripts display errors in the console?

Comment: there's no way to hide those messages. But, you could clear the console programmatically using console.clear();

Comment: Fwiw, you could delay loading YouTube videos to after your own scripts have done their work.

Comment: @nuway I've tried using console.clear(), but the issue is that since I'm displaying a welcome message, and that will always display faster than an external script, I'd be clearing that as well.

Comment: @MaratTanalin I like that idea. That way, the error would only show up, should the user navigate to the area where the video is (which happens to not be on the initial screen load)

Comment: @Joey Hicklin if it's so important to you that they see no errors, you could, theoretically, keep clearing and setting the console messages. But, I think every employer would understand that it's not your fault that youtube is throwing errors, so no big deal at all